# Is there any way that I can use non-class weapons as a Pyromancer?

Tags: dark-souls-3

If I were a certain class, and there was a piece of equipment that I wanted to use but I couldn't because I'm not the right class, is there any way I can use that equipment? I think that if I level up my dexterity enough then I can, but I want to get the facts so I don't just waste souls on a wild goose chase.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, there are no class-based weapons in Dark Souls 3. Each weapon requires certain stats in order to use effectively, which can either be Strength, Dexterity, Intelligence, or Faith. When you choose your class in the beginning, this sets your starting stats to what they would need to be in order play in the style.

- Pyromancers start off with higher Intelligence and Faith for Sorceries, Miracles, and Pyromancies
- Warriors start off with higher with Vitality and Strength to use heavy armor and weapons.
- Thieves start off with higher Luck for better drop rates
- etc...

After you choose your class, you are free to tailor your stats as you see fit when you level up. So even if you began as a Pyromancer, you are able to increase your dexterity stat to whatever you want it to be to use any weapon you desire. However, Pyromancers starts off with fairly low dexterity. If the weapon requires too high of dexterity, you might want to increase your relative magic stats first

Comment: Two-handing weapons also allow you to compensate for lower strength.  In previous games there were specific weapons that we so good I would deliberately two-hand certain spears as a caster.